# Java find specific class in groovy script

Tags: java, groovy

I have a java jar file contain interface named `IOperator` like this :

```
public interface IOperator {
    String execute(Map<String, String> parameters);
    boolean isSuccess();
}
```

now in groovy script (in single file):

```
public class ClassA {
}

public class ClassB {
}

public class classC implements IOperator {

    @Override
    String execute(Map<String, String> parameters) {
        ClassA classA = new ClassA();
        ClassB classB = new ClassB();
        return null
    }

    @Override
    boolean isSuccess() {
        return false
    }
}
```

Is there any way scan this groovy script to find that specific class implemented `IOperator` and invoke `execute` method ?

**Note: I want do it in Java code.**

Comment: In the past I've used [`Reflections.getSubTypesOf()`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.reflections/reflections/0.9.10/org/reflections/Reflections.html#getSubTypesOf-java.lang.Class-) to do this.

Comment: you could use service loader https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html

Comment: I need more details , for example when i used `scriptEngine.eval()` only load first class of script .

Comment: scriptEngine.eval() ? how it's related to your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found answer :

```
public class OperatorManager {
    public static void run(File scriptFile) {
        try {
            GroovyScriptEngineImpl engine = (GroovyScriptEngineImpl) new GroovyScriptEngineFactory().getScriptEngine();
            GroovyClassLoader classLoader = new GroovyClassLoader();

            classLoader.parseClass(new GroovyCodeSource(scriptFile));
            engine.setClassLoader(classLoader);

            Class<?>[] loadedClasses = engine.getClassLoader().getLoadedClasses();

            Class<?> operatorImplClass = Arrays.stream(loadedClasses)
                    .filter(IOperator.class::isAssignableFrom)
                    .findFirst().orElse(null);

            if (operatorImplClass != null) {
                String result = invokeMethod(operatorImplClass);
                System.out.println(result);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static String invokeMethod(Class<?> item) {
        try {
            Object instance = item.getConstructor().newInstance();
            Method execute = item.getDeclaredMethod("execute", Map.class);
            return (String) execute.invoke(instance, new Object[]{null});
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```